# Sphinx ordering: nil/NULL values last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

On a Rails project, I'm using Sphinx together with Thinking Sphinx plugin. I index a table with an attribute :foo that is a float.

My desired behaviour when sorting for column :foo would be that nil values always appear at the end of the list, e.g.

```
id; foo (order foo desc)
-------
1; 5
2; 3
3; -4
4: -5
5: nil
6: nil


id; foo (order foo asc)
-------
4: -5
3; -4
2; 3
1; 5
5: nil
6: nil
```

If it was normal sql, I'd sort like:

```
:order => "(foo IS NULL) ASC, foo DESC"
```

But it seems not to be possible, as I think NULL values are translated to 0 (is that true?). Using sphinx ordering expressions seems not to sort my floats properly.

Did anybody solve this problem or has an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you've provided is what I would suggest - as yes, you're correct, Sphinx treats NULLs as 0's.

Comment: Thank you pat.  This helped me figure out a search issue I was dealing with.  If you want to match an attribute with a nil value, you have to specify 0 instead of nil in your search conditions.

Answer (score 2):

One solution I came up with in the meantime is to index an extra attribute, like this:

```
define_index do 
  indexes foo, :sortable => true
  has "foo IS NULL", :as => :foo_nil, :sortable => true
end
```

what lets me order like this

```
:order => "foo_nil ASC, foo DESC"
```

It's a bit clumsy, especially as I have many attributes that I want to have ordered like this.

Comment: According to [the Thinking Sphinx documentation](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/indexing.html#attributes) you don't ever need to label attributes as sortable (the 'has' part), it's implicit